# how to use the method correctly in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function Person(gender) {
  this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.sayGender = function()
{
  alert(this.gender);
};

var person1 = new Person('Male');
var genderTeller = person1.sayGender;
genderTeller(); 
</script>
```

Question:

It shows 'undefined'. what is the problem with the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it in the scope of `person1`

`genderTell.call(person1);`

Answer (score 0):

Evan is right. The scope is `window` when you call the function. You need to call it on the person. When you retrieve the function like that you only get the function, not the scope.

This also works instead:

```
function Person(gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.sayGender = function () {
    alert(this.gender);
};

var person1 = new Person('Male');
person1.sayGender(); // <-- calling the function ON "person1" directly
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kq9Zw/)